# Create Private Mirror of http://nodejs.org/dist

Tags: node.js, proxy, nexus, mirror

I'd like to create a proxy or local mirror of nodejs.org to increase speed and support build repeatability.

- Sonatype Nexus fails as **nodejs.org/dist** isn't quite NPM
- Wget fails, but I'm not sure why

  wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent http://nodejs.org/dist

Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` can not mirror it because of the *robots.txt* rules. You can ignore them by using `-e robots=off`.

> If you know what you are doing and really really wish to turn off the robot exclusion, set the robots variable to ‘off’ in your .wgetrc. You can achieve the same effect from the command line using the -e switch, e.g. ‘wget -e robots=off url...’.

from [Wget Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Robot-Exclusion)

Answer (score 0):

> support build repeatability.

Ah, I suppose you want to mirror the files needed to support your `npm install` builds. npm and nodejs.org are not related that way. npm is not just a trivial web site of flat files you can mirror with wget. It's a complex web application. I would recommend just using the existing services, but if you want to pursue this, you'll want to look at [npm Enterprise](https://www.npmjs.com/enterprise).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm already using Sonatype nexus to proxy the main npmregistry, but nodejs.org isn't quite NPM.  I'm figure out how to use wget to mirror it but I need to exclude the nightlies which I don't require both as a good net citizen and to reduce the space

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install `npm` too (maybe for use in a private network) you can use a little script that I’ve written: [gist](https://gist.github.com/rluvaton/5b2314b3be878753c5bcb474483d6530)